# Why the addressbook can not remain up-to-date with ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I'm writing a custom addressbook app in ios and I use a singleton addressbookRef.

Here is my operation steps:

```
+ (ABAddressBookRef) sharedAddressBook
{
    static ABAddressBookRef ref = nil;
    if ( ref == nil )
    {
        ref = ABAddressBookCreate();
    }

    return ( ref );
}
```

step1:
   Open my addressbook app

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook];
    ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID( addressBook, 83 );
    NSString* name= ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
```

console print "aaa".

step2:

quit my app(enterBackground, not kill), change the "aaa" person name to "bbb" by using the system dialer.

step3:

open my app(enterForeground), do the same thing

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook];
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID( addressBook, 83 );
NSString* name= ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSLog(@"%@",name);
```

console print "aaa".

**My question is**

1.Why the console print "aaa", not "bbb" when used the old addressBookRef? When i change the [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] to ABAddressBookCreate(), everything seems to be ok. Why the old addressBookRef can not keep up-to-date?

2.Should I need do  ABAddressBookCreate() at enterForeground everytime?

3.is the recordID changed when I edit the person info? I suspect.

Comment: thanks.I used the solution below:
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback is being invoked when I resume back my application.But my question still exists,like this:stackoverflow.com/questions/7138718/… Should I need to recreate the ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate() in MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback? the data is stale if i just use ABAddressBookSave(the old ABAddressBookRef).

Comment: record ID remains same.. onlything is you need new Addressbook reference to get new data. It works like database instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void _ExternalChangeCallback( ABAddressBookRef bookRef, CFDictionaryRef info, void * context )
{
    HMAddressBook * hmAddressBook = (HMAddressBook *)context;

    [hmAddressBook _resetSharedRef];
}

@implementation HMAddressBook
@synthesize addressBookRef = _ref;

+ (HMAddressBook *)sharedAddressBook
{
    static HMAddressBook * volatile __shared = nil;

    if ( __shared == nil )
    {
        HMAddressBook * tmp = [[HMAddressBook alloc] init];
        if ( OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr(nil, tmp, (void * volatile *)&__shared) == false )
            [tmp release];
    }

    return ( __shared );
}


- (void)_resetSharedRef
{
    if (_ref != NULL)
    {
        ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(_ref, _ExternalChangeCallback, self);
        CFRelease(_ref);
    }
    _ref = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(_ref, _ExternalChangeCallback, self);

    if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addressBookDidResetSharedRef:)])
    {
        [_delegate addressBookDidResetSharedRef:self];
    }

}
- (void)addressBookDidResetSharedRef:(HMAddressBook *)addressBook
{
    NSLog(@"addressBookDidReset");    
    [self reloadAddressBookData_async:^(BOOL finished) {
        [completionBlock reloadData];
    }];

}
```

Now I reloadAddressbook async when _ExternalChangeCallback! reloadAddressbook need reallocate all the person(wrapped) instances, but no need to recreate it's cache data.

Comment: record ID remains same, i refetch all ABRecordRefs and get the basic data. Async reload Addressbook and do not refresh cache data(such as search indexes) when not need for raise efficiency

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that interaction with the address book is transactional. See the documentation, especially http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html. It is up to you to register to hear about changes in the database while your app is running. You should then either revert or save:

> When you receive a change callback, there are two things you can do: If you have no unsaved changes, your code should simply revert your address book to get the most up-to-date data...

Comment: ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback is being invoked when I resume back my application.But my question still exists,like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138718/abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback-works-but-data-is-stale  Should I need to recreate the ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate() in MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback? the data is stale if i just use ABAddressBookSave(the old ABAddressBookRef).